# Facebook Instant Articles for Blogger

Tags: blogger, instant

I applied my facebook page for Instant articles and it's been accepted, but I use blogger on my website and there are 2 problems.

The first is that when an article is published automatically on Facebook page IA, it shows only the title (H1) and if exists (H2)..

I think that the problem is due to inability to make all blogger posts wrapped within `<p> and </p> tags`... can anybody help me with this?

What happened instead?

The second problem is that the Featured image on "Instant Articles" always appears at the bottom of the post, though on blogger it shows under the title.

Comment: same problem with me.